# REST JSON payload case preservation

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net, flurl

Apologies if it has been asked earlier, but I could not find much on this and hence asking here.

I need to have my case preserved in my REST request JSON payload.
I used JsonProperty for the same, but it does help.

I have a class corresponding to JSON POST request payload:

```
namespace AugmentedAi.Common
{
    [Serializable]
    public class InstallSoftwareMetadata
    {

        [JsonProperty(propertyName:"sourceType")]
        public string SourceType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(propertyName: "toolInstance")]
        public string ToolInstance { get; set; }


        public static InstallSoftwareMetadata GetInstallSoftwareMetadata()
        {
            var ticketDetail = new TicketDetail
            {
                Switch = "/easy",
                Number = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

            return new InstallSoftwareMetadata
            {
                SourceType = "rest1",
                ToolInstance = "rest1",
                TicketDetail = ticketDetail
            };
        }
    }
}

public class TicketDetail
    {

       [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Switch")]
        public string Switch { get; set; }

    }
```

I get an exception from the server due to mismatched case.
In the exception message, I can see that all my request parameters have been serialized to lower-case.

What could help here? Please suggest

Edit:
This is how I am sending out the REST request. PostJsonAsync is serializing it.

```
var installSoftwarResponse = await baseUrl.WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")                        .PostJsonAsync(InstallSoftwareMetadata.GetInstallSoftwareMetadata())
                    .ReceiveJson<InstallSoftwareResponse>();
```

Comment: Whats the code that you are using to convert this to JSON. It looks like you are mixing JSON.NET and the build in Json serializer

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem?  You show your models but not how they are serialized or even teh framework(s) you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.NET you would do it like this and note that you don't need the [Serializable] attribute

```
void Main()
{
    var res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(InstallSoftwareMetadata.GetInstallSoftwareMetadata());
}

public class InstallSoftwareMetadata
{

    [JsonProperty("sourceType")]
    public string SourceType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("toolInstance")]
    public string ToolInstance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ticketDetail")]
    public TicketDetail TicketDetail { get; set; }

    public static InstallSoftwareMetadata GetInstallSoftwareMetadata()
    {
        var ticketDetail = new TicketDetail
        {
            Switch = "/easy",
            Number = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        return new InstallSoftwareMetadata
        {
            SourceType = "rest1",
            ToolInstance = "rest1",
            TicketDetail = ticketDetail
        };
    }
}

public class TicketDetail
{

    [JsonProperty("number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Switch")]
    public string Switch { get; set; }

}
```

Results

```
 {
      "sourceType": "rest1",
      "toolInstance": "rest1",
      "ticketDetail": {
        "number": "2c8b5d48-315e-406c-ad4f-b07922fdd135",
        "Switch": "/easy"
      }
    }
```